# Me llega undefined el user login

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, backend, frontend

necesito ayuda, estoy realizando un programa usando Node.js y Express para el backend y React.js para el frontend. El problema es que cuando inicio sesion con un usuario creado en la BD (MySql) y redirecciona al Dashboard pierde la sesion y me llega undefined, es decir que no me llegan los datos del usuario a la nueva seccion. Yo supongo que estoy mal en los controladores, pero no le puedo encontrar el error. Alguno que me pueda dar una mano se lo agradeceria!

Controlador:

```
 const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
 const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
 const { validationResult } = require("express-validator")
 const sequelize = require("sequelize")
 const db = require("../../database/models")

 const User= db.User


 const controller = {
    processRegister: async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.render("login", { errors: errors.mapped(), oldData: req.body }
  )
}
const newUser = {
  name: req.body.nombre,
  lastname: req.body.apellido,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
  role_id: req.body.roles
};
try {
  await db.User.create(newUser)

  const token = jwt.sign({ id: newUser.id }, "SECRET", {
    expiresIn: 86400
  })
  console.log(token,"token Guardado")
  res.status(201).json({ message: 'Usuario registrado con éxito' });
} catch (error) {
  // Manejo de errores aquí...
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al registrar el usuario' });
}
  },

     processLogin: async (req, res) => {
         try {
            const user = await db.User.findOne({
    
            where: {
                email: req.body.email
            },
  });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).send("Usuario Incorrecto",{ errors: { unauthorize: { msg: 'Usuario y/o contraseña invalidos' } } });
  }
  
  const passwordMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
if (!passwordMatch) {
  return res.status(400).send("Contraseña Incorrecta",{ errors: { unauthorize: { msg: 'Usuario y/o contraseña invalidos' } } });
}


req.session.user = {
  id: user.id,
  email: user.email,
  name: user.name,
  lastname:user.lastname
  
};

console.log(req.session.user)
if (req.body.recordarme) {
  res.cookie('email', req.session.user.email, { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 });
}
console.log("llego recordarme",req.body.recordarme)

req.session.save((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).send("Error guardado login");
  }
  console.log("llego al save",req.session.save)

  return res.status(200).json({
    id: user.id,
    email: user.email,
  name: user.name,
  lastname: user.lastname,
    
  });
  
});
console.log("llego aca 23",req.session.user)
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error during login:", error);
  return res.status(500).send("Error during login");
}
 
   },
     profile: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.session.user || !req.session.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Usuario no encontrado' });
    }
      const user = await User.findByPk(req.session.user.id,console.log(user), {
          attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
          include: ['role']
      })
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Usuario no encontrado' });
      }
  
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Perfil de usuario obtenido correctamente', user });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al obtener el perfil del usuario:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error interno del servidor' });
    }
  },

    'detail': (req, res) => {
       db.User.findByPk(req.params.id)
      .then(user => {
          let respuesta = {
              meta: {
                  status: 200,
                  total: user.length,
                  url: '/api/user/:id'
              },
              data: user
          }
          res.json(respuesta);
      });
   },

   logout: (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err);
    }
     res.clearCookie('email');
     console.log("Cierre exitoso");
     res.redirect('/');
   });
  }
  }




  module.exports = controller;
```

Rutas:

```
   const express = require("express");
   const router = express.Router();
   const mainController = require('../controllers/mainController')
  const registerValidations= require("../../validators/registerValidators");
  const loginValidations = require("../../validators/loginValidators");
 //const authorization= require("../../services/authorization")




  //router.get("/", mainController.home);

 router.post("/Registro-usuario",registerValidations, mainController.processRegister);
router.post("/login",loginValidations, mainController.processLogin)
router.get(`/:id`, mainController.profile)



 module.exports = router;
```

app.js(backend)

```
const express = require("express");
const Sequelize= require("sequelize")
const expressSession= require("express-session")
 const path = require("path");
const methodOverride =  require('method-override');
 const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
 const morgan = require("morgan")
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mainRoutes= require("./src/routes/main")
 const authenticationMiddleware= require("./services/authentication")
 const cors= require("cors")
 const app = express();

  var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true, 
   };





  let allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:3003");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // Permite cookies
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
  Accept');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
    Authorization, X-Requested-With")
   next();
   }

app.use(cors(corsOptions));




app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(expressSession({
  secret: "SECRET",
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
   sameSite: 'none',  //<===
   expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
   maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
  }
  }));
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(allowCrossDomain);
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
 app.use(morgan("dev"))


  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.user = req.session.user; // Asigna los datos del usuario a app.locals.user
     next();
  });
      app.use(authenticationMiddleware);







        app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public")));
         console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"));




       app.use("/api/user", mainRoutes)



        app.use((req, res, next) => {
       res.send("Error 404! File Not Found");
      next()
          });





       // Server Init
        const port = process.env.PORT || 3003;
       app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server escuchando en puerto 
      http://localhost:3003'));
```

Login.js

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
 import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage} from 'formik';
 import * as Yup from 'yup';
 import Header from './Header';
 import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



  function Login() {
const navigate= useNavigate()
const [rememberMe, setRememberMe] = useState(false);
const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('El correo electrónico no es válido').required('El correo 
 electrónico es obligatorio'),
    password: Yup.string().required('La contraseña es requerida'),
});
const handleSubmit = async (values,id) => {
   
    try {
        const isValid = await validationSchema.isValid(values);
        const requestBody = {
            ...values,
            recordarme: rememberMe,
        }

        if (!isValid) {
            console.error('Datos inválidos');
            return;
        }
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3003/api/user/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials:"include",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const data= await response.json()
            console.log("Inicio exitoso",data.id)
            navigate(`/Dashboard/${data.id}`, { replace: true });
        } else {
            console.error('Error envio de 400');
            window.location.href = "/api/Registro-usuario"
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
    }
};

return (

    <header className="header">

        <div className="container">

            <div className="conainer"></div>
            <div className='form'>
                <h1 className='h1'>Sistema de turnos medicos</h1>

                <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                    <Form>
                        <h2 className="h1 justify-content">Logueate</h2>
                        <div>
                            <label className="nombre justify-content">Email</label>
                            <Field type="email" id="email" name="email" />
                            <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label className="nombre justify-content">Contraseña</label>
                            <Field type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                            <ErrorMessage name="password" component="div" />
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <button type="submit" className="input btn">Iniciar sesión</button>
                            <div class="recordar">
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    name="recordarme"
                                    checked={rememberMe}
                                    onChange={(e) => setRememberMe(e.target.checked)} // Actualizar el estado al cambiar
                                /><label class="checkbox-inline">Recordarme</label>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                    </Form>

                </Formik>


                <p>
                    <Header />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
);
};

 export default Login;
```

Dashboard.jsx(aclaro no estoy llamando a los datos todavia pero en consola llega undefined con error "500"):

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import "../assets/Home.css"
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'







  class Dashboard extends Component {
state = {
  users: [],
};

componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.userId;
    
        fetch(`http://localhost:3003/api/user/${id}`)
        .then(respuesta =>{
            return respuesta.json()
        })
        .then(datos=>{
            console.log(datos.data)
            this.setState({
                users:datos.data
            })
        })
    
}
    render(){
 return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <header className="header">
    <div className="container">
        <nav>
            <Link to="/Patients" className="lista">
                Pacientes
            </Link>
            <Link to="/Doctors" className="lista">
                Doctores
            </Link>
            <Link to="/login" className="lista">
                Login
            </Link>
        </nav>

        <div>
           
                <div>
                    <h1>Bienvenido,  !</h1>
                    {/* Mostrar otros datos del usuario */}
                </div>
                
                <p>Por favor, inicia sesión para acceder al dashboard.</p>
         
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    </React.Fragment>
   );
  }
   }

  export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

haz probado el modificar tu código en el Dashboard  con el uso del useParams

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.userId;
...
```

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
...
componentDidMount() {
    const {id} = useParams();
...
```